# How to I get (this) parents child using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

Example:

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

We all know that when we want to get the value of the parent's child we can use a selector like this `("#parent #child")`. However, how can I get the child using this method. `(this+'#child')` does not do the job.

Answer (score 2):

Well!! if you are using an `id` selector you don't need to use a `context` as id is supposed to be unique... so it will be just `$('#child')` otherwise yes it would be $('childselector', this)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `this` as an context value using the [selector-context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context) model

```
$('#child', this)
```